# How can i get a connection ticket to quickbooks online for dev/testing a one off web app?

Tags: quickbooks-online

I'm trying to build a one off webapp that will communicate with our business QuickBooks Online account.  Most of the research I've found says for development and testing, use the "desktop" way of connecting (to avoid cert headaches).  So I've registered an app and got the id from here:

```
appreg.intuit.com/
```

The problem is, everywhere I've seen tell me then to go here to get a connection ticket

```
login.ptc.quickbooks.com/j/qbn/sdkapp/confirm?serviceid=2004&appid=YOUR-APPLICATION-ID-HERE
```

When I do that however, it redirects me to here

```
qbo.intuit.com/c1/v60.147/0/login?redirect=true
```

I mucked around with and finally find some way to access the "old" quick books stuff, when i went to setup a test company it sent me here

```
ptc.qbo.intuit.com/c1/v0/offline.shtml
```

which tells me

> "The QBO PTC environment is no longer available, and was replaced by the new E2E environment. Please go to https://e2e.qbo.intuit.com/ going forward. We are very sorry for any inconvenience and confusion. If you have questions, please reach out to Eric Bullen"

How can I get a connection to a test account to do some development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I get a connection to a test account to do some development?

Unless you're an Intuit employee, **you can't get a test account**.

With that said, *you don't need to*.

Just use your live QuickBooks Online account. You can sign up on their website to get a 30-day free trial if you need to.

When you register at <s>https://appreg.intuit.com</s> new link - http://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/QBOE, make sure you register in DESKTOP mode, for the PRODUCTION environment.

Then use the production URL to get your connection ticket:

- https://login.quickbooks.com/j/qbn/sdkapp/confirm?appid=YOUR-APPLICATION-ID-HERE&serviceid=2004&appdata=1

(substitute in your application ID that you get back from appreg)

More info and examples on our [QuickBooks integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition).

Comment: Well that would explain things, thanks!   I wonder was this fact mentioned anywhere and i just missed it?

Comment: You are not the only one who has missed it.  I just recently submitted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045777/create-a-test-comapny-account-for-quickbooks-online-development-and-qa-testing) with similar situations.  But a 30 day trial is not long enough for our development and QA Cycle as this is a major project and needs thorough testing.

Comment: If visiting http://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/QBOE results in a blank page, your email has not been verified with the developer platform. Visit https://developer.intuit.com/ , from top-right 'Hello, XXX' select 'Account Profile' under 'Developer Account' and you can proceed from there.