# Create a Test Company Account for QuickBooks Online Development and QA Testing

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I need to get a number of test accounts (companies) for QuickBooks Online so that we can finish developing and testing our app.  We have reached out to Intuit in order to try and obtain these and have been told to just use 30-day trials.  These periods are too short for our development cycle so we purchased accounts to use.  These accounts have been shut off / locked on us and we are just getting vague answers as to why.  We would love to know why so that we can stop doing any possible harmful activity, but alas it has been difficult to get any information in regards to that.  Our developers are more than happy to work with their engineers to make this happen.

Does anyone know how we can get test accounts so that we can test our application?

I hope that the answer is not the same as this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937391/how-can-i-get-a-connection-ticket-to-quickbooks-online-for-dev-testing-a-one-off).  We need test accounts to successfully test our application before we move forward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get true "test" (e.g. non-production accounts) from QuickBooks. They won't give you access to that environment.

If you're an IPP/Intuit Anywhere developer, submit a support ticket to Intuit with a request for a 1-year development instance of QuickBooks Online. They will send you a coupon code for a one-year free trial.

Otherwise, you're SOL.

Comment: Thank you, I have done just that and they sent me this [link](http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0010_Getting_Started/0020_Connect/Create_Sample_QuickBooks_Data) that pretty much described just that.

Comment: cepatt, I discussed this with the QBO team and we wanted to have a discussion with you as well. I wanted to find out why you were disconnected. Can you submit a support ticket and we can setup a phone call to discuss? developer.intuit.com/support  thanks - Jarred

Comment: @Jarred thank you for such a quick response.  I have submitted a ticket with the subject (As requested by Jarred Keneally).  We have heard back from your QBO team after I already asked and got a response to this question.  We have a meeting set up and I placed the details in said support case along with my contact information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Sandbox account for QuickBooks Online.

1. Register and log in to https://developer.intuit.com.
2. In the Menu, Navigate to API Docs & Tools > Sandbox ([Link](https://developer.intuit.com/v2/ui#/sandbox))

You can able to create up to 5 different companies for testing.